# A janela de "code completion" apresenta poucas alternativas de drawables a inserir

Tags: android-studio

Você percebe que existem várias bibliotecas importadas no meu Android Studio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando vou importar uma imagem para meu projeto somente aparece poucas alternativas como pode ver abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Era para aparecer mais alternativas como pode ver abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para reverter isso?

=============================================

Eu já tentei colocar o icone direto no código Java, mas não aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As opções que aparecem são as correspondestes aos *drawables* que estão na pasta `res\drawables` do seu projecto.

De facto, em versões mais antigas apareciam todas as que o seu projecto tinha acesso o que, na minha opinião, só atrapalhava.

Julgo que essa mudança se deu no Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: muito obrigado bastante esclarecedor.

Comment: Conhece algum tutorial que explique como eu coloco uma imagem no meu projeto do jeito que estou tentando fazer?

Comment: Ele terá de ser colocado primeiro na pasta `drawable`. Se for uma imagem que tem no seu PC o mais fácil é fazer copy(no explorar) e paste dela na pasta drawable(dentro do Android Studio). Ou usar o [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html?utm_source=android-studio) através de File ->New->Image Asset.